# jQuery display text nested in paragraphs inside a div

Tags: jquery, html, text, html-parsing

I have HTML that looks something like this:

```
<div class='textbox' data-title='Sometitle'>
<div class='textareaedit'>
     <p><strong>Test sample text</strong></p>
</div>
</div>
```

I'm sometimes going to have a few different `<p>` tags inside the `textareaedit` divs, and sometimes `strong` tags around the text inside the `<p>` (as in this example), and sometimes a `span` tag, and sometimes it's going to be without further tags inside the `<p>`.

I want to iterate through each `textbox` on my page, grab its title and also the text nested inside `<p>` tags in `textareaedit`. I'm giving the output via console for testing.
This is my jQuery code, but I get no output for the second `console.log()` line:

```
$('.textbox').each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    console.log($this.attr('data-title')+ ":\n");
    $this.children('textareadit').children('p').each(function(){
        console.log($(this).html()); // not giving any output, it's blank
    });
});
```

I tried `$(this).text()` as well, but no difference. You may think this example has the sample text inside `<strong>` tags within the `<p>`, but I've also tried the same example without the strong, where the text was the direct child of `<p>`, but it didn't make a difference. How can I capture the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find()` method to locate it. Try something like this:

```
$this.find('.textareadit > p').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: Wonderful thank you! The final code used `$(this).text();` but `find` did what I needed it to!

Comment: The expression I've changed on your script `.textareaedit > p` does all the magic. Check as an answer if it help you to find the final solution :)

Answer (score 2):

The class selector passed to the `children()` function is missing a `.` prior to the class name.  There is also a spelling error in the name of the class, `textareadit` should be `textareaedit`.

```
$this.children('.textareaedit').children('p').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).html()); // not giving any output, it's blank
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/aWRaS/

Answer (score 1):

```
.children('textareadit')
```

should read:

```
.children('.textareadit')
```

As you're selecting a class

Answer (score 1):

Class name is also misspelled

```
.children('textareadit') should be .children('.textareaedit')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `.` in your selector, and there is a typo in your `textareadit`. The correct one should be -

```
$this.children('.textareaedit').children('p').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).html()); // now it prints
});
```

You are passing `class selector` as argument to the first `children` call, so you should precede it with a `.`, as this is how class selectors works.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkHFZ/1/).